# TypeError: "method is not a function" error when downcasting to a subclass - discrord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, discord.js, downcast

> Please, don't mind my grammar and code mistakes because I am a self-taught coder

I am developing a multi-purpose Discord bot with [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/) using [discord.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js) and [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) libraries.

When creating the ticket system, and trying to make it as universal as possible, I ran into a problem with downcasting subclasses. To create a ticket text channel, I use `CategoryChannel.createChannel()` method, which returns `Promise<GuildChannel>`, in my case, I set the `CategoryCreateChannelOptions.type` to `"GUILD_TEXT"`, so the method returns `Promise<TextChannel>`.

After creating a channel, I want to add custom properties to it, such as `tickedID: string` (a custom random UID I generate for each ticket), `ticketGroup: string` (a group which the ticket belongs to, in order to differentiate between tickets from different categories, for example: support, suggestion, warning, form ticket categories) and `channelID: string` (ID of the channel the ticket is).

To do that, I have created a `Ticket` class, which extends `TextChannel`.

Here's a cleanified version of the `Ticket` class code:

```
// Imports
import { Guild, Message, MessageOptions, TextChannel } from "discord.js";
import { RawGuildChannelData } from "discord.js/typings/rawDataTypes";
import { TicketSetupFunctionOptions, TicketType } from "../Types/Ticket";
import { BetterClient } from "./Client";

// Ticket class
export class Ticket extends TextChannel implements TicketType{
    public ticketID: string;
    public ticketGroup: string;
    public channelContent: MessageOptions[];
    
    public constructor(options: TicketType, guild: Guild, data?: RawGuildChannelData, client?: BetterClient, immediatePatch?: boolean) {
        super(guild, data, client, immediatePatch);
        Object.assign(this, options);
    }

    // Setup method, the one which is the main problem
    public async setup<TicketSetupFunction>(options: TicketSetupFunctionOptions): Promise<Ticket> {
        // Do the code (it have never got to point of executing the code so there's no reason to put it here)
        
        return new Promise<Ticket>((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(this);
        });
        
    }
}
```

I even tried putting the `setup()` method into the type, but it didn't help. Type `TicketType`:

```
// Imports
import { MessageOptions, TextChannel } from "discord.js";
import { Ticket } from "../Structures/Ticket";

// Types
export interface TicketSetupFunctionOptions {
    channelContent: MessageOptions[];
}

export type TicketSetupFunction = (TicketSetupFunctionOptions) => Promise<Ticket>;

export type TicketType = {
    ticketID: string;
    ticketGroup: string;
    channelContent?: MessageOptions[];
    setup: TicketSetupFunction;
} & TextChannel;
```

In my `TicketManager` class (it is basically the tickets system) I have a `TicketManager.createTicket()` method, which takes a `CategoryChannelResolvable` and `OverwriteResolvable[]` as its arguments, which are then used in `CategoryChannel.createChannel()` method. It returns `Promise<TextChannel>`, but I need downcast that into returning `Ticket` if the promise resolves. Here's the `TicketManager.createChannel()` code:

```
public async createChannel(category: CategoryChannel, permissions: OverwriteResolvable[]): Promise<Ticket> {
        const channel = await category.createChannel("ticket-name", {
            type: "GUILD_TEXT",
            permissionOverwrites: permissions
        }) as Ticket;

        return new Promise<Ticket>((resolve, reject) => resolve(channel));
    }
```

`TicketManager.createTicket()` is used to create, setup and save a ticket to the database. Inside of this method I resolve the category and generate a UID for the ticket.

After that, I call `TicketManager.createChannel()` and do the following:

```
public async createTicket(categoryChannel: CategoryChannelResolvable): Promise<Ticket> {
        const ticketID = generateUID(16);
        const category = await this.client.guilds.resolve(this.guild).channels.resolve(categoryChannel) as CategoryChannel;

        const ticket: Ticket = await this.createChannel(category);
        await ticket.setup({
            channelContent: this.defaultTicket.channelContent
        });

        return new Promise<Ticket>((resolve, reject) => resolve(ticket));
    }
```

After trying to create a ticket, the program gives this error:

```
Bot\src\Structures\TicketManager.ts:47
        await ticket.setup({ channelContent: this.defaultTicket.channelContent });
                     ^
TypeError: ticket.setup is not a function
    at TicketManager.createTicket (Bot\src\Structures\TicketManager.ts:47:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async Event.run (Bot\src\Events\guildMemberAdd.ts:27:32)
```

The problem is that the method is perfectly typed and it even shows up in the autocomplete menu, but it always throws (no matter what I try to do) that error above.

I really hope somebody could help me figure this out, since it is a very important point in my bot development.

Comment: Despite the fact that you cast the result of `category.createChannel` to be a `Ticket`, that does not actually make it a `Ticket`. Recall that all types will be removed during compilation so ultimately you have only regular JS to work with. So the core issue is that whatever `category.createChannel` returns, it is not a `Ticket` instance, and so it does not have a `setup` method. Notably, you've declared a `Ticket` class, but nowhere in your code do we see `new Ticket(...)`, so it seems you have created this class but not used it. Can you show us what `category.createChannel` actually returns?

Comment: @CRice I didn't declare `new Ticket`, because I don't know if creating a channel object directly does the same as using a `category.createChannel()` method.
`category.createChannel` returns `Promise<TextChannel>`.

Comment: I see. So you have a `TextChannel` returned to you, and you want to convert it to your more specific subclass, `Ticket`. This must be achieved using the same methods as you would in plain JS. So your options are to either construct a ticket using `new Ticket` and pass the correct parameters using the data of your `TextChannel`, *or* you can manually override the `channel` prototype to point to your `Ticket` prototype instead. Eg, add a line after `const channel = await category.createChannel(...)`, which reads: `channel.__proto__ = Ticket.prototype`.

Comment: @CRice I tried using Object.assign and Object.setPrototypeOf, but they didn't help. Do I have to manually assign properties one by one after the prototype method you've shown?

Comment: @CRice after typing the prototype line of code after `category.createChannel()` it says that 
`Property '__proto__' does not exist on type 'Ticket'.`